# Holding/pushing in charger hard to charge ASUS

Tags: charging

I have to literally stand my ASUS up sideways for it to charge.  Or, when using I must push the cord in my laptop hard to keep the battery charged.  I've invested in a new charger.  But, it seems to be internal.

Comment: Can you give more info about the machine?

Comment: ASUS, Model: X54C

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the port takes a standard barrel-type plug as most other notebooks do, check and make sure that there's no debris in the jack.  If there's any residue, clean the jack out well using a cotton swab and rubbing alcohol (be sure to power it down first, and hold down the power button **after** taking out the battery to discharge it, just to be safe).  If the plug falls out easily (a common issue), there is a metal strip in the jack that produces the inward force that holds the plug in; that piece becomes loose over time and wear, and it can usually be bent back with a pair of tweezers to extend the life of the port for a bit.  Just beware that it has a limited life and will eventually break.  Unless you have a modular system, the jacks themselves are typically soldered onto the motherboard directly, so if you plan to repair rather than replace the unit, either start looking up videos on how to properly disassemble your model notebook (it can be a long and tedious process for some notebooks), or hopefully you know a guy who can handle it.  Good luck, and I hope this helps!